# MVC Core 2.0 HTML.Action vs Component.InvokeAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am really struggling with changing my mindset from the *@html.Action* way of doing things to this new *Component.Invoke* way of life.

So to outline my structure. I have a Controller called "**Contract**" with the standard Index **IActionResult**.

In there I have a partial view that is a form, which I would have normally have just loaded from the *index.cshtml* using the following:

```
if(Something = my value){
 @Html.Action("p_NewContract", new { id = x })
}
```

Which always worked.

For what I can read, I now need to make a new folder outside my nicely structured view and partial view folders under each Controller. The folder I **HAVE** to create is *"Shared/Components/p_NewContract.cshtml"*

And then in that folder, I need to create a .cs file with the postfix of ViewComponent (*p_NewContractViewComponent.cs*) And somehow the runtime will know those two things belong together?

In that CS file I then add `[ViewComponent(Name = "p_NewContract")]` before the public class and then after all that I can add to my Index.cshtml

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("p_NewContract", new { id= 2})
```

I have done all of this, no sign of it working. Am I missing something fundamental, is there a way I can get my old Html.Action back? It was so much easier.

Any assistance to help my frustration would be great!

Caz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two parts to a view component: your class that derives from `ViewComponent` and a view that component should return. By convention, your view component classes actually go in `/ViewComponents`, while again by convention, your view goes into `Views/Shared/Components/{component name}/Default.cshtml`.

That's just convention, though. The same as how Razor automatically finds views based on controller/action name. In truth, the classes can go wherever you like. They are brought in via reflection, so as long as it's somewhere in the assembly or a referenced assembly, it will be found. The views likewise can be moved wherever you like, you just have to tell it where to find them, since it won't be able to do it automatically based on convention anymore. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components#view-search-path